# prevent my library from 'exporting' a dependency in maven, but still have it in runtime classpath

Tags: maven

My library, call it my-util-lib, uses slf4j as the logging facade. I need a concrete slf4j binding at runtime when I use my library directly, but I don't want the binding jar to be 'inherited' when an application imports my-util-lib. I know I can declare the dependency scope as 'test' in the POM of my-util-lib to accomplish this, but then I cannot run my library directly, other than in JUnit tests. Like if I want to run a main() method from one of my util classes for some quick-n-dirty purpose or quick test. 
Is there a way to accomplish this? Or to force the scope of a run to 'test' when not running a JUnit test?

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that I want to do this in eclipse. Like from a random class select Run->Run As -> Java Application   and it have it run the main() method of that class, and have the slf4j binding jar on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
<scope>provided</scope
```

on the `<dependency>` to slf4j.

For a discussion of the values of `scope`, see this question: [What's the difference between these Maven dependency scopes: provided/compile/system/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907682/whats-the-difference-between-these-maven-dependency-scopes-provided-compile-sy)

Comment: That works. But why? From the maven docs: "This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive".. It seems it would not be on the normal runtime classpath.

Comment: @crig I've added a link to an explanation.

Comment: ok, so I guess when you 'run as java application' in eclipse, it is just using the compilation classpath, so that's why this works. Correct?