# maven dependency declaration for libraries that are also distributed as standalone jars?

Tags: java, maven

I have a standalone maven project, let's call it `foo-lib.jar`, which depends on `slf4j-api.jar`

1. Another project `bar-app.jar` depends on

   - `foo-lib.jar`
   - a bunch of other libraries
   - `slf4j-api.jar`
   - the log4j backend for SLF4j
2. The `foo-lib.jar` project can be built and run standalone, and it includes an additional runtime dependency

   - `slf4j-jdk14.jar`

My question is: how can I declare this runtime dependency for  `slf4j-jdk14.jar` without forcing it on the `bar-app.jar` project? (which maven scope should I use)

(It's also hard for me to test the effect of this on `bar-app.jar`; the `bar-app.jar` project is complicated and for some reason it doesn't build on my machine, so instead I work with that project's maintainers.)

I've read these other SO questions but it is still confusing for me.

- [Maven: how to override the dependency added by a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library)
- [Can a program depend on a library during compilation but not runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070570/can-a-program-depend-on-a-library-during-compilation-but-not-runtime)
- [Maven : what is the "runtime" scope purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272499/maven-what-is-the-runtime-scope-purpose)
- [What's the difference between these Maven dependency scopes: provided/compile/system/import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907682/whats-the-difference-between-these-maven-dependency-scopes-provided-compile-sy)

Comment: You can use the concept of optional dependencies, please refer to the linked question. It means adding `<optional>true</optional>` to the dependency on `slf4j-jdk14` inside `foo-lib`.

Comment: does this work with `<scope>runtime</scope>`? (why would you ever use it with compile-time scope anyway? compile-time dependencies are always transitive... oh wait, no they're not. Project A class `AFoo` could have a compile time dependency on Project B interface `Bar` with an optional runtime dependency on Project B class `BarImpl`, which in turn has a compile time dependency on Project C class `Baz`. So A depends on B and B depends on C but A doesn't necessarily depend on C.)

Comment: Yep, you can use it with `<scope>runtime</scope>`. It will have the same effect as `<scope>compile</scope>` really because its only goal is to say: "whoever is depending on me doesn't always need that dependency so don't consider it when resolving transitive dependencies".